# How to generate zeros array in php

Tags: php

I need to generate zeros array in php, but don't know how to generate it using php. i can do it using js.

In js array zeros code is:

```
for (let _i = 0; _i < 25; _i++) {
   let n = new Array(_i).fill(0)
   console.log(n);
}
```

Generated like this:

```
[]
[ 0 ]
[ 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

how can i generate like this using php array?

```js
for (let _i = 0; _i < 25; _i++) {
  let n = new Array(_i).fill(0)
  console.log(n);
}
```

Comment: with [array_fill](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

Comment: how to using array_fill?

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++) echo json_encode(array_fill(0, $i, 0)).PHP_EOL;` https://3v4l.org/AL1o3

Comment: <?php 

$desiredNumber = 25;
for ($i=0; $i <= $desiredNumber ; $i++) { 
 $innerArr = array();
 for( $j=0; $j <= $i; $j++ ){
  array_push($innerArr, 0);
 } 
 echo '['.implode(', ', $innerArr).']';
 echo "<br>";
}

?>

Comment: @musabbir-mamun wow its also working `<?php $desiredNumber = 25; for ($i=0; $i <= $desiredNumber ; $i++) { $innerArr = array(); for( $j=0; $j <= $i; $j++ ){ array_push($innerArr, 0); } echo '['.implode(', ', $innerArr).']'.PHP_EOL; } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

[`array_fill()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++) {
    $n = array_fill(0, $i, 0);
    echo implode(', ', $n) . PHP_EOL; // output imploded for readable reasons
}
```